# On a LAMP stack, how to limit the number of concurrent connections and serve a static page for those who are beyond that limit?

Tags: apache-2.2, connections

I'm aware of the Apache directives `MaxClients` and `ListenBacklog`. I'm trying to set a limit of, let's say 100 concurrent connections after which the new connections will be served a static page. Can this be done? Should `MaxClients` and `ListenBacklog` be higher or lower than that limit? How can I test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:
Let's say that I want to allow X concurrent requests, after which the following Y concurrent requests will stay in a queue, waiting for the frist X to finish, and everything exceeding X+Y will be served a static page:

1. In `httpd.conf` the following directives must be set:

   ```
   MaxClients X
   ServerLimit X
   ListenBacklog Y
   ```
2. Logged as root in MySQL, set `max_connections`:

   ```
   set global max_connections = X
   ```
3. Edit the `.htaccess` file from your server's public root folder:

   ```
   ErrorDocument 503 error_503.html
   ```
4. Make sure that your error_503.html is served in one request. All stylesheets and scripts must be in this file. If you want to include images, you'll have to use the [data uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Also, you'll have to slice your images up because in IE data URIs have to be smaller than 32KiB.

Comment: I don't how you'd get apache to serve the 503 once the backlog is full. This is a TCP backlog, which is opaque - as far as I know, applications can't even get its size, but can only dequeue from it by accepting connections.

Answer (score 3):

If Apache can't accept the incoming connection because it's already handling MaxClients, then it can't serve a static page.  So, I don't have any hard evidence, but I don't see how you could achieve this with just Apache alone.  You might be able to put something in front of Apache which returns a static page if Apache returns a connection failure, but it seems like a lot of complex config to me.  Hopefully someone will be along to prove me wrong.

Comment: I believe you are correct; is there a way then to set MaxClients to, let's say, 300, and configure Apache to serve the static page when it reaches 100 simultaneous connections?

Comment: Not from within Apache that I'm aware of.  Maybe you need to step back from the detailed question, and ask a more general question such as, for busy sites, how do you gracefully handle the situation of exceeding Apache's MaxClients value.